# Coffeescript callback scoping issue

Tags: coffeescript, hubot

Hi i'm trying to write a addon script for hubot. I seem to have a problem with scoping. The reference of "msg" inside the fork callback is undefined, i don't seem to get any variables in the callback.

I've also had this same issue with the built-in jira-issues.coffee! Yesterday in that script the jiraUrl was undefined in the callback. This morning it was working again and now it's stopped working again (after i restarted hubot). I've never even modified it.

Has anyone experienced anything like this?

```
githubApi = require("node-github")

module.exports = (robot) ->
  github = new githubApi { "version": "3.0.0" }
  github.authenticate { "type":"basic", "username":process.env.HUBOT_GITHUB_USER, "password":process.env.HUBOT_GITHUB_P
ASSWORD }
  robot.respond /kickstart\s(\S+)/i, (msg) ->
    name = msg.match[1]
    msg.send name
    base_url = process.env.HUBOT_GITHUB_API || 'https://api.github.com'
    github.repos.fork {"user":"Raven", "repo":"Raven","org":"codedemos"}, (err,data) ->
      if err
        msg.send "error :("
      else
        msg.send "Fork Complete..."
```

it compiles to

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
(function() {
  var githubApi;

  githubApi = require("node-github");

  module.exports = function(robot) {
    var github;
    github = new githubApi({
      "version": "3.0.0"
    });
    github.authenticate({
      "type": "basic",
      "username": process.env.HUBOT_GITHUB_USER,
      "password": process.env.HUBOT_GITHUB_PASSWORD
    });
    return robot.respond(/kickstart\s(\S+)/i, function(msg) {
      var base_url, name;
      name = msg.match[1];
      msg.send(name);
      base_url = process.env.HUBOT_GITHUB_API || 'https://api.github.com';
      return github.repos.fork({
        "user": "Raven",
        "repo": "Raven",
        "org": "codedemos"
      }, function(err, data) {
        var id;
        if (err) {
          return msg.send("error :(");
        } else {
          return id = data.id;
        }
      });
    });
  };

  msg.send("Fork Complete...");

}).call(this);
```

Which looks fine yet running it yields:

```
ReferenceError: msg is not defined
  at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/kbot/scripts/kickstart.coffee:48:2, <js>:36:3)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/kbot/scripts/kickstart.coffee:33:1, <js>:38:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost certainly a whitespace problem with that last line. Triple-check you are using consistent indentation in the whole file and make sure your file has a final newline after `msg.send "Fork Complete..."`. I copied and pasted your coffeescript code and compiled it to javascript and the last `msg.send` line gets correctly put `inside` the proper function, vs your js above which has that line in the wrong place.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't notice that! Is that a requirement of coffeescript, to have a blank line at the eof? I should probably use an editor that can display whitespace in the future! Thanks.

Comment: Basically coffeescript needs to understand when the indentation level changes, and in this case you can't end a file with an indented line and no newline. If your last line of the file was flush left, you wouldn't hit this edge case. In any case, it has always been unix best practice to end all text files with a newline, so set your editor to just do it automatically. And yes, if you are going to code in whitespace-significant languages its best to use an editor with good ability to display and manipulate whitespace.